# Turn a global into an npm, browserify, etc. module

Tags: npm, requirejs, browserify

I've built out this simple library `https://github.com/FarhadG/script-tag-data` and you can either clone it down or install via `bower` but I'm curious how I should go about turning it into an `npm`, `browserify`, etc. module.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have your project on github, for publishing to npm, you can follow the guide over here : [npm-developers](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers)

AFAIK, browserify doesn't have a registry. You probably meant bower. Follow this guide : [Creating Packages](http://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/)

And maybe use Google search next time, yeah?

Comment: The project is already on NPM and Bower, however, the question was intended to ask on how to provide it via a `module.exports` for convenience.